# PHP Eclipse : comments displayed in a color I can't change

Tags: php, eclipse

I have recently installed *Eclipse* on a *Debian 8.9* Machine, with the *Arc Dark Theme* on both the OS and *Eclipse*.

As you can see on the image below, some comments are displayed in a dark grey which makes it impossible to read without selecting it. Not very practical.

[image: PHP Comment Wrong Color Eclipse]

The problem is that when openning a file with such comments, they are first displayed in green, as set in `Preferences - PHP - Editor - Syntax Coloring` but immediately change to this grey color. In the settings, **PHPDoc**, **PHPDoc Comment**, **Single-line Comment** and **Multi-line Comment** are all set to the green you can see on the screenshot.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the _Arc Dark Theme_ on Eclipse? Via the _[Eclipse Color Themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=46940)_ plug-in?

Comment: That's right. Can't remember the format though.

Comment: Do you have other plug-ins installed? E. g. the _[Darkest Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme)_ may cause this issue.